# TWain dsm 32 bit select default scanner

Tags: c#, scanning, twain

I am working on windows c# application and I need to add scanning feature. I installed a demo project that uses twain_32.dll and it works good , however I can not embed it in my system as my system is 64 bit.

HOw can I embed it without changing the projects build target.
Is there a way to Iterate over the scanners using
twain_32.dll and set which one to use without showing the twain dialog for the user to select ?

Comment: Get 64 bit library? https://github.com/twain/twain-dsm/tree/master/Releases/dsm_020402/windows/64

Comment: Helllo . than you , is there any code samples on how to use it ?